# node.js, mongo.db, db.collection.find with query parameter 1 from a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filtering

I want to filter a mongodb collection. The filter criterion comes from another collection, eg. the id which is transported by a query string.

If the query filter (first parameter) is fixed it works fine:

```
collection.find({fsuser:/575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2/},{},function(e,docs){  
    res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
        "notiz_tabelle": docs
    });
});  //Ende find()
```

Now I want a variable instead of /575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2/.

I tried to use a dynamic object:

```
//Dynamisches Objekt
var dynQueryObjekt = {};
dynQueryObjekt["fsuser"] = "/575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2/";


collection.find(dynQueryObjekt,{},function(e,docs){  
    res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
        "notiz_tabelle": docs
    });
});  //Ende find()
```

Does not work. Does somebody know how to filter a mongodb collection with a variable as input?

Here some further information: Version MongoDB 3.2.6. The whole code looks like:

```
/* GET Notizen DB page. */
router.get('/notiz_tabelle', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;

//Query-String auslesen
    var qstring1 = req.query;


   console.log("Mitteilung");
   //von JSON in String wandeln
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(qstring1);
    console.log("Query-String: " + jsonString);

    //Hash aus String kopiren
    var subString = jsonString.substring(11, 35);

    console.log("Teilstring: " + subString);

   var collection = db.get('notizcollection');
    //String in Befehl kopieren, wie??
    jsonString = '{fsuser:/' + subString + '/}';

    console.log("Json String: " + jsonString);

    //Dynamisches Objekt
    //var dynQueryObjekt = {};
    //dynQueryObjekt["fsuser"] = "/575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2/";

   // console.log("Dyn Objekt: "+JSON.stringify(dynQueryObjekt));


     var dynQueryObjekt = {};
     dynQueryObjekt["fsuser"] = new RegExp("/5762620c59a7aef450417047/", 'i'); 



    //var jsonAusdruck=JSON.parse(jsonString);    
    //console.log("JSON Ausdruck: "+JSON.stringify(jsonAusdruck));


var someInput = '/5762620c59a7aef450417047/';
var reg = new RegExp(someInput, 'i');


//collection.find(jsonString, {}, function (e, docs) {
//collection.find({fsuser: /#{subString}/}, {}, function (e, docs) {
//collection.find({fsuser:/5762620c59a7aef450417047/},{},function(e,docs){     //funktioniert
//collection.find({"fsuser":"/5762620c59a7aef450417047/"},{},function(e,docs){  //fkt nicht, nur ohne Anf. Zeichen
    collection.find(dynQueryObjekt, {}, function (e, docs) {
//collection.find({fsuser: {$regex: reg}}, {}, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
            "notiz_tabelle": docs
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Your code looks correct assuming you are trying just find by fuser (i.e. with out regex). Did you check with db.collection.find ("fsuser", "575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2") on mongo shell whether you are getting results?

Comment: I tried in the console:

Comment: I tried in the console: `db.notizcollection.find({"fsuser": "/5762620c59a7aef450417047/"}).pretty()` => no error, no result, but with no quotation marks it works: `db.notizcollection.find({fsuser: /5762620c59a7aef450417047/}).pretty()` works fine.

Comment: Could you please update your question with one sample document and mention the mongo data type of fsuser? If you are using the older version of mongo, please mention that as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you are trying to use Regex in your query, this should work

```
var someInput = '575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2';
var reg = new RegExp(someInput, 'i');

collection.find({fsuser: {$regex: reg}}, function(e, docs){  
    res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
        "notiz_tabelle": docs
    });
});
```

Comment: Does not work. The error has somehow to do with the quotation marks. In the console `db.notizcollection.find({fsuser: /5762620c59a7aef450417047/}).pretty()`works. As soon as I use an object there are quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp directly on your variable.

The **i** is for case-insensitive match.

```
var dynQueryObjekt = {};
dynQueryObjekt["fsuser"] = new RegExp("575f13cf6eb9d09fdf0f14c2", 'i'); 



collection.find(dynQueryObjekt,{},function(e,docs){  
    res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
        "notiz_tabelle": docs
    });
});  //Ende find()
```

Comment: db.notizcollection.find({fsuser: {$regex: /5762620c59a7aef450417047/ }}).pretty() works, but when I want to use a variable it doesent.                   var meinstring='5767dc33e9075b97cd98e2f5';
var reg = new RegExp(meinstring, 'i');
db.notizcollection.find({fsuser: { $regex:reg }}).pretty() does not work

Answer (score 0):

By the time I got a workaround of this problem: Appearently collection.find(myFilter) does not like '"' in the attributes of the JavaScript objects.

I decided to have manual numeric (int) keys to join two tables. The index i fetch by req.query is a string. So i have to make a number out of it by Number().

```
/* GET Notizen DB page (routes/index.js */
router.get('/notiz_tabelle', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;

    //Read Query String from other page
    var queryObjekt = req.query;  //read Query-Objct
    var zahl=queryObjekt["fsuser"];  //Read Number-String from JSON-Object 
    console.log("Wert "+zahl);
    wert=Number(zahl); //String to Number

    var queryString=JSON.stringify(queryObjekt);
    console.log("Query-String: "+queryString);    

    var collection = db.get('notizcollection');   

    //First parameter of find() is Filter, must be Numeric, not String
    collection.find({fsuser:wert}, {}, function (e, docs) {  
        res.render('notiz_tabelle', {
            "notiz_tabelle": docs
        });
      });
   });
```